# Laravel query returns builder instead of collection

Tags: php, laravel, builder

I am new to laravel and trying to have a result. 
My code is this:

```
class GegonosController extends Controller
{
    public function index($gid = null, $cid = null, $nid = null)
    {
        if (is_null($cid) and is_null($nid) and is_null($gid)) {
            $gegon = Gegono::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get(); 
        }
        else{
            if(!is_null($gid)) {
                if($gid == 0) {
                    $gegon = Gegono::where('gegtype_id','>',1);
                }
                else{
                    $gegon = Gegono::where('gegtype_id', '=', $gid);   
                }
            }
            else {
                $gegon = Gegono::where('gegtype_id','>',0);
            }
            if (!is_null($cid)) {
                $gegon->where('city_id', '=',$cid);
            }
            if (!is_null($nid)) {
                $gegon->where('nomos_id','=', $nid);
            }        
            $gegon->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get(); 
        }                        
        $nomoi = \App\Nomoi::orderby('name')->get();
        return view('front.gegonota', compact('gegon','gid','cid','nid','nomoi'));
    }
```

In the first, if when all variables are null the result is a collection of all the records of the table.
In all other, if (other cases) the result is a builder and I get no results,

It doesn't show any error but gives no results.

Any help would save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query Builder's `get()` method **returns** the collection of records. In your code, you just call `get()` method in the air, so it does nothing. You should assign it to a variable or use it in an expression.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#collections

Comment: Wait a second i assign it in the variable $gegon i think its obvious. And then the variable passes in view front.gegonota. This Is not the problem. Something else.

Comment: In your `if`, yes. But in your `else` it's not assigned. There is a Query Builder in your `$gegon` variable and you call `get()` on it, but it doesn't mean `$gegon` becomes a collection (like I explained in my answer). Try this: `$gegon = $gegon->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get(); `.

Comment: I already told you what is wrong here, now it's your turn to just apply it.